# How can rand() make random numbers, even when you don't seed it with time(NULL)?

Tags: c, function, random

I understand that what's passed into `srand()` as an argument will be used as the seed for calls to `rand()` that happen afterward.  Generally `time(NULL)` is passed in.

But if you only call `srand` once, and then you have `rand` being called continuously in a loop, how are the numbers different from each other?  The seed was the value returned from `time(NULL)`...but ONLY that one specific return value is being used.  So how are different numbers being generated?

I don't know anything about threading in C.  But is `srand` using threads and a different seed each time so that subsequent calls to `rand` actually do return random numbers?  I noticed that when I pass a static number to `srand` instead of `time(NULL)`, the `rand` is still generating random numbers.

Comment: You only perceive the numbers to be random.  Please see the Wikipedia article on the subject of [Pseudorandom Number Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).  As to whether there is an underlying order to the universe in which there's no such thing as a "true" [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) or if everything has a deterministic pattern if you look hard enough...see movies like ["Pi"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNOQUPmgbnY).

Answer (score 4):

The draft C99 standard provides a sample implementation in section `7.20.2.2` *The srand function* that will probably clear up how it work for you:

> EXAMPLE The following functions define a portable implementation of rand and srand.
>
> ```
> static unsigned long int next = 1;
> int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
> {
>     next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
>     return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
> }
>
> void srand(unsigned int seed)
> {
>     next = seed;
> }
> ```

`srand` set the *static* variable `next` which is then set to new value in `rand` and then subsequent calls to `rand` will pick up with the previous value of `next`.

For example if we used `srand(1)` then the sequence would look like this as we make calls to `rand`:

```
next = 1
next = 1                   * 1103515245 + 12345  = 1103527590
next = 1103527590          * 1103515245 + 12345  = 1217759518843121895
next = 1217759518843121895 * 1103515245 + 12345  = 15426401326682203284
```

As HostileFork points out, the numbers are not truly random but are [Pseudorandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which says:

> also known as a deterministic random bit generator (DRBG),[1] is an
>   algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers whose properties
>   approximate the properties of sequences of random numbers. The
>   PRNG-generated sequence is not truly random, because it is completely
>   determined by a relatively small set of initial values, called the
>   PRNG's seed (which may include truly random values). Although
>   sequences that are closer to truly random can be generated using
>   hardware random number generators, pseudorandom number generators are
>   important in practice for their speed in number generation and their
>   reproducibility.

This particular implementation is using a [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: Do you have a _reason_ for using the `static` qualifier in this context?

Comment: @self well this is from the C standard so I did not choose this but basically it is a global variable which is a way to share state between `rand` and `srand`. The C standard library is in general not reentrent and the standard even says `The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify
objects with static storage duration`.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for clearing that up! Really what I was looking for was the "picking up from the previous 'next'" part.