# What algorithm is Rand() based on in C language?

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I have been researching the source code of Rand() for a while, but until now I couldn't figure out the whole picture of the function.

The following are the source codes found and researched by me:

[rand.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;h=db0b214473c44b9c1acacf1ebd00e8f5c9ef639b;hb=HEAD)

[random.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;h=7c033df9aa5d62be3a7bd6f2d1ac43cf9f4478c4;hb=HEAD)

Could somebody provide some advices or assistance for me?

Thanks a million!

Comment: See [here](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Maybe this link http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/ ?

Comment: Note the [C99 draft standard provides a sample implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26395067/1708801) but does not require a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *required* to be based on *any* specific algorithm but many will use a [linear congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) algorithm to generate the sequences. This basically changes the seed along the following lines:

```
seed = (seed * multiplier + adder) % modulo
```

and then deliver some portion of the seed as a random value. The values for `multiplier`, `adder` and `modulo` can vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Rand is based on several things like mac address which should be unique on every machine. there are several implementations to verify that the returned value is "random"